# Escaping the quote identifier while reading insert statement from a .sql file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python.

As part of the script, I am opening a file to read, adding the each line to list and executing the insert into table.

Snippet:

```
def convertFileToList(input_file):
    try:
        global ins_list
        ins_list = []
        f = io.open(input_file,'r',encoding='windows-1252')
    except IOError:
        pcm.write_log(log_fname, 1, "Could not read file:" + input_file + "\n")
        return -1

    with f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('\n','')
            ins_list.append(line)
        f.close()
        return ins_list
```

Insert:

```
def insert(list):
    rows_affected = 0
    try:
        chk_db_conn()
        for query in list:
            db_cursor.execute(query)
            db_conn.commit()
            if (db_cursor.rowcount < 0):
                pcm.write_log(log_fname, 1, "No rows were affected")
            else:
                rows_affected = rows_affected + db_cursor.rowcount
    except:
        return -1
```

Here, the list is nothing but the Insert statement in the sql file

After this, I am iterating the list and performing db_cursor.execute().

But, I have a problem when every there is a single quote in the insert statement the execution fails:

Example:
Insert into TABLE (Id,name,ColName,Val1,Val2) values (11,'tableName','name','Inter','Intern's');

Is there way to check if there is a quote identifier with the word then escape and insert that row ?

Comment: You are performing `db_cursor.execute` wrong. You should show this part of your code, too.

Comment: Will update that

Comment: @coldy you can try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html

Comment: @faost, I am using pymssql for the purpose to connect to database. I am able to insert successfully to Database if there are no single quoted strings.

Comment: and where do you construct the INSERTs?

Comment: All the inserts are in a sql file. I am reading the file line by line, storing it into a list and executing the query

Comment: So then your file is corrupt. Who is this file created?

Comment: No, because I can insert all rows if it does not have a single quote.
Example:
Inserts into table:
Insert into TABLE (Id,name,ColName,Val1,Val2) values (11,'tableName','name','Inter','Intern);

Does not insert into table:
Insert into TABLE (Id,name,ColName,Val1,Val2) values (11,'tableName','name','Inter','Inter'n');

This has a single quote in the insert values

Comment: If a file contains statements, that lead to errors, the file is called corrupt.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for your comments but i think I got the solution for this by recreating the insert statements as well via python.